# Error rendering on ec2 : Specified pix_fmt is not supported

Tags: rendering, transparency, file-format

Here is the context, i have a amazon ec2 micro instance with ubuntu 14.04 and with blender 2.78 installed, i have a custom blend file with in output : file_format is H.264, color_mode is RGBA, in Encoding format is AVI and Codec is PNG. The problem is that when i launch rendering by the command line, the render fails and in the log i get this message :

Error: Specified pix_fmt is not supported

It may be a ffmpeg problem which i installed prior to blender following this :
http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/

When i render it locally (Ubuntu 16.04, ffmpeg, blender 2.78) it works just fine.

Has anyone any idea how to resolve this?

Thanx.

Comment: In general is not a good idea to render directly into a video format. Render as an image sequence and then encode the video later.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your remote FFMPEG is missing one of the legion of codecs when it was compiled. You will need to use a version compiled with the codec required.